# Matlab: Distinguish land from ocean in harbors

Tags: matlab, plot, harbor, geoplot

I'm trying to distinguish land from ocean in harbors in Matlab. I have tried using the highest resolution maps from gshhs, but it isn't detailed enough. Below are is an example showing that it isn't detailed to the level I want. The one to the left showing the coastline boundaries and the other one showing the geoplot with `basemap = 'streets'`.

Comparison of the basemap and coastlines:

[image]

Since the map is able to plot in such detail, shown below, I would imagine that it should be able to distinguish land from ocean, just based on the colors.

Zoomed in basemap:

[image]

Appreciate any help here! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah, just select the pixels with the exact match of blue, its just a number. Albeit you will have problems with the grid and the street names, so you may want to figure out how to remove them first. Albeit admitedly, the best solution is to find a database with accurate coasts.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that seems to be the only solution. Do you have any code/link to an easy implementation?

Comment: I am sure the best solution is to find better data. In any case, a quick google search for color matching in images will give you as olution